# mysql select as statement combined with find and replace

Tags: mysql

Im trying to select a value from a table using Select As, so that I can then use that value in a find & replace statement.  This is what I have so far, but no  luck:

SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key=description and post_id IN (22179,22182) AS "video", update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content,"[description]","video")

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AS` is for renaming columns that you `SELECT`, so it would look like this:

```
 SELECT meta_value as video from ...
```

which isn't what you want.  You're after `SELECT INTO`, e.g.

```
 SELECT meta_value INTO @my_var from ...
```

And then you can use @my_var later.

See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html).